# Proguard apk of maven project in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, proguard

On my current Android project, I have moved from Eclipse to Android Studio. My current project is a maven project (When I'll have time I will move it from Maven to gradle !). But right now I need to generate an Proguarded APK but right now, it is not protected (I have successfully decompiled it :().

The files I was using for my proguard are :

- project.properties with the follwoing line (+ Project target I won't describe) :

  ```
  # To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):

  proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-google-api-client.txt:proguard-project.txt
  ```

Android studio tells my that proguard.config is unused...

- proguard-generated.cfg
- proguard-google-api_client.txt
- proguard-project.txt

Do you know if there are some actions to do when migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio to keep the proguard fonctionnality ?

Thank you by advance.